# Using Agg to find most frequent user per day

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have some twitter data

```
username    time
RamiAlLolah 2016-03-11
grezz10     2016-02-19
DawlaWitness11  2016-04-08
murasil1    2016-04-29
mustaklash  2016-02-19
```

I'd like to be able to determine who was the most frequent tweeter on each day.  I can group the dataframe in terms of days and then use `df.username.value_counts().reset_index().ix[0,0]` to get the most frequent tweeter on that day.

Can I do this for the entire dataframe using `agg`?  To find the most frequent tweeter for each day, can I do something like `r.agg( lambda x: x.username.value_counts().reset_index().ix[0,0])`?  Or is there a better way to do what I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) by [`dt.date`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.date.html) with aggregating [`mode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mode.html) and last [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reset_index.html):

```
print (df.username.groupby(df.time.dt.date).apply(lambda x: x.mode()))
```

Sample:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'time': {0: pd.Timestamp('2016-03-11 00:00:00'), 1: pd.Timestamp('2016-02-19 00:00:00'), 2: pd.Timestamp('2016-02-19 00:00:00'), 3: pd.Timestamp('2016-02-19 00:00:00'), 4: pd.Timestamp('2016-04-08 00:00:00'), 5: pd.Timestamp('2016-04-08 00:00:00'), 6: pd.Timestamp('2016-04-29 00:00:00'), 7: pd.Timestamp('2016-02-19 00:00:00')}, 
                   'username': {0: 'RamiAlLolah', 1: 'grezz10', 2: 'grezz10', 3: 'grezz10', 4: 'DawlaWitness11', 5: 'DawlaWitness11', 6: 'murasil1', 7: 'mustaklash'}},
                    columns = ['username','time'])
```

```
print (df)
         username       time
0     RamiAlLolah 2016-03-11
1         grezz10 2016-02-19
2         grezz10 2016-02-19
3         grezz10 2016-02-19
4  DawlaWitness11 2016-04-08
5  DawlaWitness11 2016-04-08
6        murasil1 2016-04-29
7      mustaklash 2016-02-19

print (df.username.groupby(df.time.dt.date)
                  .apply(lambda x: x.mode())
                  .reset_index(drop=True, level=1)
                  .reset_index())

         time        username
0  2016-02-19         grezz10
1  2016-04-08  DawlaWitness11
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to take the mode of each time and concat solutions

```
r = pd.concat([df[df.time == i].mode() for i in df.time.unique()])
```

*optional* for the index you could do (as you prefer your results)

```
r = r.reset_index(drop=True)
```

or

```
r.set_index('time', inplace = True)
```